# The telesign distribution was not found and is required by the application with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

This is a part of a code that I have, this part of the code that corresponds to sending an SMS through an API called telesign. The code works perfectly if I run it from Pycharm, the SMS is sent without any type of problem, but when I run pyinstaller to end my project it gives me a certain error that I show below:

```
from telesign.messaging import MessagingClient

customer_id = "2170F10E-D4FB-4C0F-8252-A4C32ECD459B"
api_key = "I8qrRIlwrIjrUxTNA0otl9TSfktjsDuz7VzFnFGS0CFdEzT4MIJbje75XU4OsX5LmtiPBXiytAF+xQ8Sd+yiDA=="
phone_number = "5352659475"
message = "alerta"
message_type = "ARN"
messaging = MessagingClient(customer_id, api_key)
response = messaging.message(phone_number, message, message_type)
```

when I run pyinstaller it gives me this error

```
The telesign distribution was not found and is required by the application with pyinstaller
```

As you can see it has something to do with not finding something related to telesign.